# How to transform a list of dictionaries into another format more elegantly?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a json file with some information about words. The structure is a list with dicts and looks like this:

```
file = [{"index": "1", "text": "uhm", "eos": false}, {"index": "2", "text": "moeten", "eos": false}, {"index": "3", "text": "langs", "eos": false}, {"index": "4", "text": "uhm", "eos": true}, {"index": "1", "text": "uh", "eos": false}, {"index": "2", "text": "om", "eos": false}, {"index": "3", "text": "die", "eos": false}, {"index": "4", "text": "afsluiters", "eos": true}]
```

I need to preprocess the data in order to do some further analysis. Therefore, I've written the following function. It's working, but doesn't look very elegant. How could it be improved in order to make it more readable, less redundant, and just beautiful =)

```
def prepare(file):

    # set up variables
    text = []
    sent_dict = {}
    sentence = ""
    chunks = []
    ngram = ""
    maxn = 5

    for word in file:

        if word["eos"] == False:
            # concatenate words
            sentence += word["text"] + " "

            # get last five elements of sentence excluding last space and make chunk
            chunk = " ".join(sentence.split(" ")[:-1][-maxn:])
            index = word["index"]
            chunks.append({index: {"ngram" : chunk}})

        else:
           # concatenate words without last space
           sentence += word["text"]

           # get last five elements of sentence and make chunk
           chunk = " ".join(sentence.split(" ")[-maxn:])
           index = word["index"]
           chunks.append({index: {"ngram" : chunk}})

           # make dict with sentence and list of chunks
           sent_dict["sentence"] = sentence
           sent_dict["chunks"] = chunks
           text.append(sent_dict)

           # set variables back to default
           sent_dict = {}
           sentence = ""
           chunks = []

    return(text)
```

If you compile `prepare(file)`, it will return a list looking like:

```
[{'sentence' : 'uhm moeten langs uhm', 'chunk' : [{'1' : 'uhm'}, {'2' : 'uhm moeten'}, {'3' : 'uhm moeten langs'}, {'4' : 'uhm moeten langs uhm'}]}]
```

Comment: Please show us an example output of the function you have written. Also show us an example of the output you want.

Comment: If you insert the list at the top of the question into the function, it returns exactly the output I want. It's a working example

Comment: Yes, but please post an example anyway. Lots of people can come up with solutions without looking through code.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that for every single sentence there are on 4 chunks. If that's no the case im sure you can easily adjust my code but for now its sort of hard coded for 4 items. This can most definitely be changed though.
The way i decided to output that information is in a list. 
For me i thin lists are much easier to work with and play around with than dictionaries and therefore the way i made it is as follows:
It will be a list filled with items like

```
sentence,uhm moeten langs uhm : sentence is made up of the following chunks : 1,uhm : 2,uhm moeten : 3,uhm moeten langs : 4,uhm moeten langs uhm
```

and the next item in the list would be

```
sentence,uh om die afsluiters : sentence is made up of the following chunks : 1,uh : 2,uh om : 3,uh om die : 4,uh om die afsluiters
```

The reason i made it like this is because it is easily split able you can easily get every item you want, for example you can split by

```
" : "
```

and then after you can loop through and split by

```
","
```

to get very item.

your code in the end for me looked like the following.

```
def prepare(file):

    # set up variables
    text = []
    sent_dict = {}
    sentence = ""
    chunks = []
    ngram = ""
    maxn = 5

    for word in file:

        if word["eos"] == False:
            # concatenate words
            sentence += word["text"] + " "


            chunk = " ".join(sentence.split(" ")[:-1][-maxn:])
            index = word["index"]
            chunks.append({index: {"ngram" : chunk}})

        else:

            sentence += word["text"]

            chunk = " ".join(sentence.split(" ")[-maxn:])
            index = word["index"]
            chunks.append({index: {"ngram" : chunk}})

            sent_dict["sentence"] = sentence
            sent_dict["chunks"] = chunks
            text.append(sent_dict)

            sent_dict = {}
            sentence = ""
            chunks = []

    return(text)



file = [{"index": "1", "text": "uhm", "eos": False}, {"index": "2", "text": "moeten", "eos": False}, {"index": "3", "text": "langs", "eos": False}, {"index": "4", "text": "uhm", "eos": True}, {"index": "1", "text": "uh", "eos": False}, {"index": "2", "text": "om", "eos": False}, {"index": "3", "text": "die", "eos": False}, {"index": "4", "text": "afsluiters", "eos": True}]



final_list = []
x = (prepare(file))
for i in x:
    new_string = "sentence,{} : sentence is made up of the following chunks : 1,{} : 2,{} : 3,{} : 4,{}".format(i["sentence"], i["chunks"][0]["1"]["ngram"], i["chunks"][1]["2"]["ngram"], i["chunks"][2]["3"]["ngram"], i["chunks"][3]["4"]["ngram"])
    final_list.append(new_string)
```

Remember the list with the items formatted in my way is called final_list. If you loop through and print each item you will see what I showed you. Hope this is easier to work with.

Comment: Remember that also the portion of the output that says "sentence is made up of the following chunks" can easily be removed after a split of the original string, this is because it will always be in position one of the split list so you can just go ahead and pop it out every time if needed. Hope that the code helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer. The idea is nice and seems useful for some assignments. However, I need the output as specified and don't want to improve the output format, but functions which return that output. Furthermore, sentences can consist of more than 4 chunks and the amount of chunks varies from sentence to sentence.